# SQLite iOS DB delete old records

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to build a DELETE statement for my SQLite DB that will make sure that anything over X number of records will be deleted. I'm not too familiar with SQL so I'm not sure how to write this, and I also need to make sure the records are sorted by a date field first, which is stored as an INTEGER, so that I make sure I'm keeping the newest X rows and deleting the older records.

Any help on how to do this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to sort the records and you don't need sub-selects. Just do `delete from table where datefield < int_value`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be accomplished in SQLite using Sub Query and making use of limit

Here your subquery will return all ID which are needed to deleted based on your limit X(5). I hope it will help you

```
 DELETE FROM TABLENAME WHERE ID IN ( 
    SELECT ID FROM TABLENAME 
    WHERE DATE < strftime('%s','now') limit 5
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query similar to the following. You should probably have an index on your date column too.

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE date_column >= (
    SELECT date_column 
    FROM mytable 
    ORDER BY date_column 
    OFFSET num_rows_you_want_to_keep 
    LIMIT 1 
)
```